# Layer toggle disappears leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, openlayers

I'm having a bit of trouble finalizing a project I'm working on. When I upload my map to filezilla, my map layer toggle doesn't show up:

before uploaded:
[image: map image1]

after uploaded:
[image: map image 2]

Does anyone have any idea why that is happening?

adoran93.bol.ucla.edu/final/167finalAD.html

Comment: It's not possible to give a sensible answer just with the 2 pics. Is it possible to access your online page ?

Comment: yes, here it is: http://adoran93.bol.ucla.edu/final/167finalAD.html

thanks!

Comment: @AllisonDoran You might want to post that link on the question body as well. That way other people can see it instead of hunting for it in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to upload 2 files

```
<script src="nzoutline.geojson"></script>
<script src="sectors.geojson"></script>
```

They should be in the same directory as 167finalAD.html